# css clamp function with auto not working as min, value, max

Tags: html, css, clamp

I have am using css `clamp()` to adjust height of my div, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
.container{
    height: clamp(200px, auto, 400px);
}
```

but works well when

```
.container{
    min-height: 200px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

from the documentation [css clamp(): MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) , it says it does the job of `min, value and max`. why is it not working?

Comment: you cannot use auto inside clamp

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's sad. It would have been helpful if container can be set to wrap items, with min and max height values. Thanks, I'll head back to the old way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you check [the syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()#formal_syntax) you can see:

```
clamp( <calc-sum>#{3} )
where 
<calc-sum> = <calc-product> [ [ '+' | '-' ] <calc-product> ]*
where 
<calc-product> = <calc-value> [ '*' <calc-value> | '/' <number> ]*
where 
<calc-value> = <number> | <dimension> | <percentage> | ( <calc-sum> )
```

`auto` is not a part of the syntax which is logical since you cannot compare `auto` with pixel value (or any length)

You think that the browser will first apply `auto` to height in order to find the value of the height based on the content then convert that value to `px` and then apply the `clamp()` using that value but no. It doesn't work that way.

The browser will try to first resolve `clamp(200px, auto, 400px)` which is invalid because `auto` is not a `<calc-value>`. We don't even need to know to which property its applied.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with `min-content` either, which you might expect to have even more of a definitive width :-(